# Adding a subview to an NSStatusBar Item causes 100% CPU

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am trying to create more sophisticated controls in a Statusbar Item. I already managed to make my code work by replacing the view on the statusBarItem, but this is being deprecated and carries some other visual inconsistencies.

I am trying to add a row of buttons to a single item on the Menubar. When I add these as a subview for the statusBarItem.button, this causes the CPU load to increase to 100% continuously.

I have reproduced the issue into the following few lines of code that can be added into a new XCode project with Storyboard (edit AppDelegate):

```
var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    //...
    statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    statusBarItem?.button?.title = "Hello World"
    let button = NSButton(title: "Button2", target: self, action: #selector(printYes))
    statusBarItem?.button?.addSubview(button)
    //...
}
```

After starting the program the CPU load will be continuously at 100%.

System info: MacOS 11.6.2 XCode 13.2.1

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I am quite unexperienced in Mac UI programming.

Comment: Overlaying a button with a button doesn't seem to make sense. Try to add the custom button to an `NSView` and this view to the status item button. And why is `statusBarItem` optional? You can declare `let statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my original code this was wrapped in a `NSView`, but the issue persists regardless.

I copied that from somewhere else. Good to know that this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this issue seems to exist as long as Text is attempted to be added inside the Status Item Button as a subview.

I circumvented this issue in my project by rendering an image of an button with text on it in the subviews.

An example of how I did it (albeit with a lot of hard-coding):

```
func generateImage(symbol: NSString, active: Bool, visible: Bool) -> NSImage {
    let width = 24
    let height = 16
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    let canvas = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    let image = NSImage(size: size)
    let imageFill = NSImage(size: size)
    let imageStroke = NSImage(size: size)
    
    let strokeColor = NSColor.black
    if active || visible{
        imageFill.lockFocus()
        strokeColor.setFill()
        NSBezierPath(roundedRect: canvas, xRadius: 6, yRadius: 6).fill()
        imageFill.unlockFocus()
        imageStroke.lockFocus()
        symbol.draw(in: NSRect(x: 9, y: -1, width: 16, height: 16), withAttributes: [.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11), .foregroundColor: strokeColor])
        imageStroke.unlockFocus()
        
        image.lockFocus()
        imageFill.draw(in: canvas, from: NSZeroRect, operation: .sourceOut, fraction: 1.0)
        imageStroke.draw(in: canvas, from: NSZeroRect, operation: .destinationOut, fraction: active ? 1.0 : 0.5)
        image.unlockFocus()
    } else {
        image.lockFocus()
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        NSBezierPath(roundedRect: canvas, xRadius: 6, yRadius: 6).stroke()
        symbol.draw(in: NSRect(x: 9, y: -1, width: 16, height: 16), withAttributes: [.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11), .foregroundColor: strokeColor])
        image.unlockFocus()

    }
    image.isTemplate = true
    return image
}
```